# UICollectionViewCell side-by-side

Tags: ios, user-interface, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have UICollectionView in my custom keyboard, and it has two rows of cells with same heights, but different widths (size comes from server), direction of scroll is horizontal.

How can I show collection items side by side, without this strange centering which based on the previous cell width?

[image: My result]

Comment: As such there is no centering of cell by default Flow layout tries to place the cell within the row if its possible using the minItemSpace attribute. Play with FlowLayout little more it will work for you easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achivied needed result with [SKRaggyCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/tralf/SKRaggyCollectionViewLayout)

[image]
P.S. If you'll use SKRaggyCollectionViewLayout, don't forget to put
`self.layout.variableFrontierHeight = NO;` to have same heights for all cells.